# Access denied when doing "net start ndisprot"

Tags: windows-7, ndis

I have compiled the `ndisprot` sample from the Windows DDK (`src\network\ndis\ndisprot\60`) for Windows 7 64 bit.

I have installed it, but in doing `net start ndisprot` says

> system error 5 and access denied.

My admin says that I have admin privileges (i.e., he can't give me more privileges).
Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you open the command prompt with admin privilages.

Go to `"cmd"` and right click and open as "administrator"